# C++ Error: Too Many Initializer Values

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, multidimensional-array

I'm having a weird error with my arrays. I have declared them like so:

```
void Interface::setup(){
    char pitchPlayers[9][26] = {
        { 201, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 187 },   //1
        { 186, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 186 },   //2
        { 186, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 001, '1', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', 001, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 186 },   //3
        { 186, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 186 },   //4
        { 186, ' ', 001, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 001, '2', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '2', 001, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 001, ' ', 186 },   //5
        { 186, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 186 },   //6
        { 186, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 001, '3', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '3', 001, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 186 },   //7
        { 186, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 186 },    //8
        { 200, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 188 },   //9
    };

    char dice[9][9] = {
        { 201, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 187 },    //1
        { 186, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 186 },    //2
        { 186, ' ', 254, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 186 },    //3
        { 186, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 186 },    //4
        { 186, ' ', ' ', ' ', 254, ' ', ' ', ' ', 186 },    //5
        { 186, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 186 },    //6
        { 186, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 254, ' ', 186 },    //7
        { 186, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 186 },    //8
        { 200, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 188 },    //9
    };
}
```

Then I have the too many initializer values error on the 2nd row of the array when I want to change the contents of my array like so:

```
if (numberOfPlayers == 3) {
    pitchPlayers[9][26] = {
        { 201, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 187 },   //1
        { 186, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 186 },   //2 - this line
        { 186, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 001, '1', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', 001, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 186 },   //3
        { 186, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 186 },   //4
        { 186, ' ', 001, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 001, '2', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '2', 001, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 001, ' ', 186 },   //5
        { 186, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 186 },   //6
        { 186, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 001, '3', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '3', 001, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 186 },   //7
        { 186, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 186 },   //8
        { 200, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 188 },   //9
    };

    for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 26; y++) {
            cout << pitchPlayers[x][y];// cout << "X";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

I have declared them properly in my header files and such. I can't find what the problem would be. I'm fairly new to C++ so it is probably a rookie error somewhere.

Comment: `setup` declares two arrays whose lifetime is limited to the `setup` function, so it is useless.

Comment: In your second code-snippet, you can't initialize or assign to arrays like that. Perhaps you should declare the arrays as member variable, and either initialize them in the constructor one way or another (through the constructor initializer list, or by copying from local arrays)?

Comment: You'll have to declare those arrays out of the `setup` function in order to access them in another function.  It would be best to declare them in the header file, and initialize them in your setup function.  Perhaps you should just change your setup function to be the object's constructor.  That would be the best practice in this case.

Comment: Still having the problem after moving the arrays outside the function

Comment: Btw, this looks like you could use some better learning material. Using built-in arrays in today's C++ is not a great idea, as is that `setup` member method probably.

Comment: Without moaning about my uni lecturer, you are totally correct

Comment: note that CHAR_MAX is 127 on common systems; consider using `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`

Comment: You seem mixed up between array declarators and array access. When declaring an array you write `char x[9][26] = .....` to specify the dimensions. But later on, the array is known as `x`.  Writing `x[9][26] = ` attempts to modify the element at row 9, column 26 (which does not even exist); and you get "too many initializers" because you provided multiple "initializers" for changing a single element.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. How would I change an entire array at the same time then?

Comment: You change an entire array by changing each value, or `memmove`ing from an array containing all new values

Answer (score 0):

Besides changing the scope of `pitchPlayers` as was written in the comments,
regarding changing the entire array after the declaration :
You can delclare another initialized array called for example `pitchPlayersFor3`. 
Preferably declare it `static` and `const`.
Then you can use `memmove` to copy from `pitchPlayersFor3` to `pitchPlayers`.